# How do I get a list of required fields in a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have a model with many different required fields. Is there a way to retrieve a list of only the fields that are required? 
I don't believe ModelName.validators works because I only want the fields that are required. I have also tried ModelName.column_names but that gives me all the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModelName.validators` seems to work when you filter the returned list for `presence` validators:

```
ModelName.
  validators.                                        
  grep(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator). # only `presence`
  flat_map(&:attributes)                              # only their attribute names
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get a list of required fields in a model in Rails?

You can get it by calling:

```
# Refactor if needed
Model.validators.select{ |v| v.instance_of?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator) }.map{ |v| v.attributes }.flatten
```